# number of ordered pairs of (p,q)

Tags: combinatorics

Let $r, s,t$ all are positive numbers and $p,q \in N$ such that the l.c.m of p and q is $ r^2 * s^4 * t^2$ .
Then what is the number of ordered pairs of $(p,q)$ ?
I am getting the answer $3*5*3$ .Is it the answer?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Number of factors of $r^2*s^4*t^2$ is (2+1)*(4+1)*(2+1) not ordered pair.And that too only when $r,s$ and $t$ are prime numbers.

Comment: @ItiShree: It will be $(2*2+1)(2*4+1)(2*2+1) = 225$

Comment: Yes answer is 225 .why don't you write a complete proof?.

Comment: @HariShankar why are we multiplying here with 2?

Answer (score 4):

Since I am familiar with the problem (it appeared in an exam in India a few years ago), I believe you meant that $r,s,t$ are primes. Under that assumption, $p = r^{a_1}s^{b_1}t^{c_1}, q = r^{a_2}s^{b_2}t^{c_2}$

Hence $\max (a_1,b_1) = 2, \max (a_2,b_2) = 4, \max (a_3,b_3) = 2$

Now the pairs $(a_1,b_1)$ such that $\max (a_1,b_1) = 2$ are $(0,2), (2,0), (1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$ making for 5 choices. In general if $\max (a_i,b_i) = n$ we have $2n+1$ pairs of choices.

Hence the number of pairs $p,q$ will be $5*9*5 = 225$